# EXCEL: SNUMBER inside IF statement with INDIRECT

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I use the excel formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,INDIRECT({"D3","D6","D8"}),0))
```

And put a number in C2 and in D3 (or D6 or D8), the result is TRUE.

However, once I wrap this formula inside an IF statement (inside the same cell:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,INDIRECT({"D3","D6","D8"}),0)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

the same input number is always FALSE.

Why would wrapping the first formula inside an IF statement suddenly negate the result?

Comment: You need to confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: I did use Ctrl-Shift_Enter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Choose instead of Indirect.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C2,CHOOSE({1,2,3},D3,D6,D8),0)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

This is an array formula and depending on your verion on may need to confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: That works! Thank you very much!